# Problemas al realizar consultas en Firebase con Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Estoy utilizando Android Studio para realizar una aplicación, utilizo a firebase como base de datos para la aplicación, puedo agregar datos desde la aplicación a dicha base de datos, el problema es cuando realizo consultas a firebase no funcionan y no me generan ningún error

~
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder_Nota viewHolder_nota, int position, @NotNull Nota nota) {
viewHolder_nota.SetearDatos(
getApplicationContext(),
nota.getId_nota(),
nota.getUid_usuario(),
nota.getCorreo_usuario(),
nota.getFecha_hora_actual(),
nota.getTitulo(),
nota.getDescripcion(),
nota.getFecha_nota(),
nota.getEstado()
);
}

```
            @Override
            public ViewHolder_Nota onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull  ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_nota,parent,false);
                ViewHolder_Nota viewHolder_nota = new ViewHolder_Nota(view);
                viewHolder_nota.setOnClickListener(new ViewHolder_Nota.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(Listar_Notas.this, "on item click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(Listar_Notas.this, "on item long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                return viewHolder_nota;
            }
        };

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Listar_Notas.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        recyclerviewNotas.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerviewNotas.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (firebaseRecyclerAdapter!=null){
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

~
Si pudierais echarme una mano os lo agradecería

Comment: Hola Dani Moreira, bienvenido, Para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar). Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Muchas gracias Marce, he intentado pegar el código pero me daba error, acabo de colocar un enlace con dicho código

Comment: Agrega el código esencial del problema que describes, que consulta estas realizando? Revisar [ask], saludos.